# Linux 5.9 kernel schedule

Tags: kernel, dell, xps

I recently got a new laptop using a Tiger Lake CPU and Intel XE Iris graphics.
This is an XPS 13, and an upgrade from an earlier XPS 13 model from 3 years ago.

The performance on this computer (on Ubuntu 20.10) is absolutely terrible though, so I did some research and it sounds like the next Linux 5.9 kernel will have better support for Tiger Lake related things.

Given that Groovy Gorilla is out, does it mean that the next (5.9) kernel will only appear in Ubuntu 21.04, or can we expect it to land earlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel 5.11 will be in Ubuntu 21.04, which will be released April 2021.

- The same kernel will be in Ubuntu 20.04.3, which will be available for 20.04 users around July 2021.
- Kernel 5.11 (and intermediate kernels) will not be backported to Ubuntu 20.10. It will "land earlier" only for pre-release testers.

The [Ubuntu Kernel Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam) welcomes skilled community testers to help find problems with the pre-release kernel.

Answer (score 5):

The intended kernel for 21.04 is 5.11 (since gnome 40 is the intended desktop) so we are probably not going to get an Ubuntu version of the 5.9 kernel.

But... you can already install the mainline 5.9 kernel (so that is without any Ubuntu related tweaks) (prefer to do this on 20.10). Default installation method for kernels:

```
cd /tmp/
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_all.deb    
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-headers-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb    
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb   
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9/amd64/linux-modules-5.9.0-050900-generic_5.9.0-050900.202010112230_amd64.deb    
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

and to remove it select boot with the previous kernel from grub and do ...

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-unsigned-5.9.0-050900-generic
```

Comment: As someone who hasn't done this, is it easy to test this and go back to an earlier kernel in case this didn't work well?

Comment: Ah I think you covered that in your last paragraph. Thank you! I will give this a shot. I accepted the other answer as it's a bit more complete.

Comment: Please note that these kernels are not supported and hence do not get any security updates.